# Use Sveltekit and Tailwind CSS

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css, svelte-3, sveltekit

Sveltekit is finally in [public beta](https://svelte.dev/blog/sveltekit-beta). Does anyone know how to use it with Tailwind CSS? There aren't any official docs for this integration.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you're using SvelteKit, you can also look at using the [Svelte Adder for Tailwind](https://github.com/svelte-add/tailwindcss).

From their README:

> You must start with a fresh copy of the official SvelteKit template,
> which is currently created by running this command:
>
> `npm init svelte@next`
>
> Once that is set up, run this command in your project directory to set
> up Tailwind CSS:
>
> `npx svelte-add tailwindcss  # --jit`

That command will perform the Tailwind setup for you, so you don't have to create all the configs yourself.

Comment: almost too easy! Seriously though, very nice! was excited to see a similar adder for Bulma.io

Comment: Just a note there's currently a bug with it: https://github.com/svelte-add/tailwindcss/issues/42#issuecomment-835858863

Answer (score 9):

Luckily, setting up Tailwind CSS in Sveltekit is easy.

#### 1. Install Sveltekit

If you don't have a Sveltekit project already, now's the time to create one.

```
npm init svelte@next
npm install
```

#### 2. Install Tailwind CSS

Assuming you already have Svelte

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

If you want to use [just in type compilation for Tailwind](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-jit), install that, too.

```
npm install -D @tailwindcss/jit
```

#### 3. Run Tailwind setup

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Next, change the created `tailwind.config.js` to a commonjs module by renaming it to `tailwind.config.cjs`. You just need to change the extension to `cjs`.

Then, inside the config, setup which pages/components to purge from.

```
// tailwind.config.cjs
module.exports = {
    purge: ['src/app.html', 'src/**/*.svelte'],
...
}
```

#### 4. Create styles.css

Create a `styles.css` file in the src folder.

```css
// ./src/style.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Now, create a layout component to import the styles from.

```
// ./src/routes/$layout.svelte
<script>
    import '../style.css';
</script>
```

#### 5. Connect Sveltekit with Tailwind

This is the final step.

In your `svelte.config.cjs` file, add postcss as a preprocessor.

```js
// svelte.config.cjs
module.exports = {
    // add this
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
        postcss: true,
        defaults: {
            style: 'postcss',
        },
    }),
}
```

And create a `postcss.config.cjs` file in the root of the project.

```js
// postcss.config.cjs
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'tailwindcss': {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
```

*If you're using `@tailwindcss/jit`, replace `tailwindcss` above with `@tailwindcss/jit`.*

That's it! You're now ready to use Sveltekit and Tailwind CSS.

*P.S. Credit goes to [Matt Lehrer](https://www.mattlehrer.com/blog/setting-up-tailwindcss-in-sveltekit-with-vite/) for writing a great blog post on the subject.*

Answer (score -2):

The OP @Nick states:

> There aren't any official docs for this integration.

In fact, there is, at least on TailwindCSS's site:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit

They're not unlike the steps outlined in another answer here (in fact, they may be authored by the same person?)

> Start by creating a new SvelteKit project if you don't have one set up already. The most common approach is outlined in the Getting Started with SvelteKit introduction.

```
npm init svelte@next my-app
cd my-app
```

> Install Tailwind CSS
> Install tailwindcss and its peer dependencies via npm, and then run the following commands to generate both tailwind.config.cjs and postcss.config.cjs.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init tailwind.config.cjs -p
mv postcss.config.js postcss.config.cjs
```

> Add the paths to all of your template files in your tailwind.config.cjs file.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

> Create a ./src/app.css file and add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers.

```
<script>
  import "../app.css";
</script>

<slot />
```

> Run your build process with `npm run dev`.

> Start using Tailwind’s utility classes to style your content.

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
  Hello world!
</h1>
```